# How to wash a hydration pack (not resevoir)?

Tags: accessories, cleaning

What's the best way to wash the pack part of a hydration pack (not the resevoir/hose)? Is it just like a back pack: cold water and a little detergent with air/tumble dry low?

Comment: What are the care instructions included with it (and perhaps sewn into a label)?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I found from Dakine (brand I have), guess I should've trusted Google first!

> **DAKINE Pack Washing Instructions**
>
> We recommend washing your DAKINE backpack by hand in cold water with a mild detergent and soft bristled
>   brush. If hand washing is not going to do the trick, the second option
>   is to use a "front loader" washing machine. This is better because it
>   has no center post for straps to catch on. There is still a chance the
>   straps could catch so place your pack inside a pillowcase or mesh bag
>   before washing. Wash your pack in cold water with a mild detergent on
>   gentle cycle, Do not bleach your pack. Hang to dry in a warm but shady
>   place, the sun could change the color of your pack. Switching the pack
>   from inside out to right side out throughout the drying process is the
>   best way prevent mildew. Damage caused by washing packs or bags will
>   not be covered by warranty.

Comment: You should accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned and you've discovered, the safest way to clean it is to simply follow the manufacturer's instructions.

That said...

My girlfriend and I both have Camelbaks. Their [website](http://www.camelbak.com/en/sitecore/content/CamelBak/Global/Support/Product-Care/Cleaning/How-to-clean-your-CamelBak-pack.aspx) says: "DO NOT wash your pack in a washing machine." I've done this with both our bags a whole lot of times and have never had a problem. I've also put a bunch of backpacks through the washing machine that weren't supposed to go there, never with a problem. (Can you tell I'm lazy?) And a hydration pack is basically just a backpack with a special compartment for the bladder, and maybe a bit of extra padding or insulation.

I would, however, recommend hang drying them, no matter how you choose to wash it. Dryers can get hot enough to melt the nylon that these kinds of bags are made out of. Low is probably safe, but why risk it? They easily dry overnight, even indoors.

Comment: I put my pannier (without frame) through the washer once.  What came out was sort of a Dali interpretation of a pannier.

Comment: I've never tried it with a pannier. Ortliebs are easy enough to just hose off.

Comment: Well, in the pannier's defense, it had led a hard life up to that point -- easily 10K miles in all sorts of weather, including snow.